# how to pass the value of a button to angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wanted to pass my button value to angular js through a function. I tried passing the function with the ng-model but it's not working in the case of a button. So can anyone help me with this thanks in advance

html:

```
<p align="center">
    <a href="#category1" id="select1" ng-model="select1" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" value="Category 1" ng-click="catFn1()">Category 1</a>
</p>
```

angular js:

```
$scope.catFn1 = function () {
    var sel1 = document.getElementById('select1').innerHTML;
    alert(sel1);
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast(sel1); //----- making the button value available through out the code
    return dict1(sel1);
}

function dict1(sel1) {
    alert(sel1);
    $("#dictation1").click(function () {
        window.location = "#pageeight";
    });
}
```

I actually wanted to perform controller communication using factory method I just know to communicate by this method. So I need to pass my value through a function.All the answers are valued.

Comment: Why don't you try like this catFn1('Category 1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access current object via `e.target` property. From there you can grab `value` attribute.

```
 <a href="#category1" ng-click="catFn1($event)" data-value="Category 1" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Category 1</a>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.catFn1 = function (e) {
    var sel1 = e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast(sel1);
    return dict1(sel1);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use the return function . Is there any other way to pass the button value directly?

Comment: Not sure, I get. Pass where?

Comment: I need something like this

Comment: $scope.catFn1 = function (button_value) {
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast(button_value);
}

Comment: So don't return, I don't know why you need `dict1` at all.

Comment: yea you are right @dfsq :) actually I meant without this  var sel1 = e.target.getAttribute('data-value'); is it possible to pass the button value directly

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `ng-click="catFn1('Category 1')"`?

Answer (score 1):

plnkr = http://plnkr.co/edit/b1bFqZdoGVNyC5KOCkJp?p=preview

ng-click's value is an expression, see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <p align="center">
      <a href="#category1" 
          id="select1" 
          ng-model="select1" 
          data-transition="slidedown" 
          class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" 
          value="Category 1" 

          ng-click="catFn1();select1 = $event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('value').textContent">

          Category 1

      </a>

      select1 = {{ select1 }}
    </p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you Nyopi for the plunker but I was in need of a function that can pass the value of a button to angular js now I got it

Comment: `$event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('value').textContent` helped me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, its not a button its an anchor.

Try this:

```
<a href="url" onclick="test(this)">Text</a>

function test(control){

alert(control.innerHTML)

}
```

Comment: thanx Nishad for your answer.This is just javascript I needed in angular js